# Creating a Fancy looking Loop Table

Tags: javascript

I made a loop table where you can enter how many columns and rows you want and it would make the corresponding table for you. However, I was instructed to make the background color and the text color to be something else than black and white, and not only that, each time when the table generates, the first row must be in a different color than all the others. How do I do that? I will post my code so far down below

```js
var rows = window.prompt("How may rows?");
var columns = window.prompt("How many columns?");
document.writeln("<table border=1>");
for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
  document.writeln("<tr>");
  for (var c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
    document.writeln("<td>Hallo</td>");
  };
}
document.writeln("</table>")
```

```css
body {}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Loop-Table</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
```

Comment: Short answer: learn CSS.

Comment: Sidenote: your javascript code shows techniques that have been obsolete close to 20 years. So if you're learning from a resource that teaches to use `document.writeln()` as the main 'render to screen' method, I would suggest to find a more up-to-date reference.

Comment: "the first row must be in a different color than all the others" Good thing the `th` tag exists, then !

Comment: In order to style a table, have a look at [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_boxes/Styling_tables)